# loading content on separate page that's encased in the jcycle plugin

Tags: ajax, jquery, jcycle

So I have a website that has just two pages. On the home page, there are some things going on, but are not important. There are some links, however, that will need to link to a specific piece of content on the second page.

On the second page, I have content on there and it's all encased in the jcycle plugin.

What I need to do is if someone is on the homepage and they click on a link, it needs to load up the second page and show the correct "slide" that corresponds to what the homepage link is.

If you need any more clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Show us some code or a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In the [cycle options reference](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), I see that there is a `startingSlide` option. You could set that dynamically. You could either do it with server-side code, e.g. `/foo?slide=3` or you could check which anchor reference was used on the incoming link, e.g. `/foo#slide3`. Or, you could use DHTML to build the slideshow on the homepage when they click the given link.

Also note that there is a `slideExpr` option that you could use to filter the slides to a smaller set, depending on what they selected.

Comment: I'm with @Jed who asked you to post some code or a jsFiddle. Please show some effort to solve your own problem before asking the community to solve it for you.